# Add dimensions to denormalized concatenated columns queried from temporary tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, denormalization

I am querying two tables from an oracle database.  POS.SNAPSHOT_SUMMARY_LOG contains daily snapshots of all reserved orders from today into the future. POS.SALES_SUMMARY_LOG contains final sales history until yesterday.  I am trying to create a denormalized table that has a column with sales figures at different points in time (i.e. WINDOWS). The query below works well and is fast. I get a column for each sum for each window. See results for 2/26/18-3/26/18 [windows_query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCNPz.jpg). (The PREVIOUS_YEAR__DATE column is the most similar weekday from the previous year and not the same calendar date of the previous year)
However, I can't figure out how to group by the dimensions of PRODUCT_CATEGORY, CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, SALES_CHANNEL to the results so that the query runs quickly.

```
    WITH SNAP AS( SELECT 
    TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-SNAPSHOT_DATE AS WINDOW, CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, PREVIOUS_YEAR__DATE, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, SALES_CHANNEL, QUANTITY, REVENUE 
    FROM POS.SNAPSHOT_SUMMARY_LOG
    WHERE (SNAPSHOT_DATE IN (TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD'), TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-7, TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-365,TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-372))),

    HIST AS  (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, PREVIOUS_YEAR__DATE, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, SALES_CHANNEL, QUANTITY, REVENUE 
    FROM POS.SALES_SUMMARY_LOG)

    SELECT DISTINCT SNAP.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, SNAP.PREVIOUS_YEAR__DATE,

    CONCAT(SNAP0.REVENUE,HIST0.REVENUE)+0 AS REVENUE0,
    CONCAT(SNAP7.REVENUE,HIST7.REVENUE)+0 AS REVENUE7,
    CONCAT(SNAP365.REVENUE,HIST365.REVENUE)+0 AS REVENUE365,
    CONCAT(SNAP372.REVENUE,HIST372.REVENUE)+0 AS REVENUE372,

    CONCAT(SNAP0.QUANTITY,HIST0.QUANTITY)+0 AS QUANTITY0,
    CONCAT(SNAP7.QUANTITY,HIST7.QUANTITY)+0 AS QUANTITY7,
    CONCAT(SNAP365.QUANTITY,HIST365.QUANTITY)+0 AS QUANTITY365,
    CONCAT(SNAP372.QUANTITY,HIST372.QUANTITY)+0 AS QUANTITY372

    FROM SNAP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM SNAP WHERE WINDOW=0 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) SNAP0 ON SNAP.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE=SNAP0.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM SNAP WHERE WINDOW=7 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) SNAP7 ON SNAP.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE=SNAP7.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM SNAP WHERE WINDOW=365 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE ) SNAP365 ON SNAP.PREVIOUS_YEAR_DATE=SNAP365.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM SNAP WHERE WINDOW=372  GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) SNAP372 ON SNAP.PREVIOUS_YEAR_DATE=SNAP372.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM HIST WHERE CURRENT_YEAR_DATE<TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-0 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) HIST0 ON SNAP.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE=HIST0.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM HIST WHERE CURRENT_YEAR_DATE<TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-7 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) HIST7 ON SNAP.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE=HIST7.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM HIST WHERE CURRENT_YEAR_DATE<TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-365 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) HIST365 ON SNAP.PREVIOUS_YEAR_DATE=HIST365.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_YEAR_DATE, sum(REVENUE) AS REVENUE, sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM HIST WHERE CURRENT_YEAR_DATE<TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DDD')-372 GROUP BY CURRENT_YEAR_DATE) HIST372 ON SNAP.PREVIOUS_YEAR_DATE=HIST372.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE
WHERE SNAP.CURRENT_YEAR_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SysDate,'YEAR') AND ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TRUNC(SysDate,'YEAR'),'Y'),15)
```

Comment: Your `hist` subquery doesn't look right; presumably it starts with a `select`, but does it not have a where clause on it, to restrict the rows returned to the 4 specified dates? Also, I'm curious as to why you're using the CONCAT function here, rather than, say, an arithmetic operator or, at least, a better way of differentiating which part of the resultant string is the current and which is the historical amount (e.g. `snap0.revenue || ':' || hist0.revenue`

Comment: I fixed the query. Sorry for the cut and paste.

Comment: When I don't use the concat function I get duplicates of dates in the POS.SALES_SUMMARY_LOG and  POS.SNAPSHOT_SUMMARY_LOG with blank results in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite your query using conditional aggregation, which ought to be a lot more performant than your current query.

E.g. I think you could rewrite it to be something like:

```
SELECT current_year_date,
       previous_year__date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 0 THEN revenue END) snap_revenue0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 7 THEN revenue END) snap_revenue7,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 365 THEN revenue END) snap_revenue365,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 372 THEN revenue END) snap_revenue372,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 0 THEN revenue END) hist_revenue0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 7 THEN revenue END) hist_revenue7,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 365 THEN revenue END) hist_revenue365,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 372 THEN revenue END) hist_revenue372,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 0 THEN quantity END) snap_quantity0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 7 THEN quantity END) snap_quantity7,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 365 THEN quantity END) snap_quantity365,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trunc(sysdate) - snapshot_date = 372 THEN quantity END) snap_quantity372,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 0 THEN quantity END) hist_quantity0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 7 THEN quantity END) hist_quantity7,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 365 THEN quantity END) hist_quantity365,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_YEAR_DATE < (trunc(sysdate) - 372 THEN quantity END) hist_quantity372
FROM   pos.snapshot_summary_log
GROUP BY current_year_date,
         previous_year__date;
```

I don't quite understand what you mean by "add the dimensions of PRODUCT_CATEGORY, CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, SALES_CHANNEL"; if you mean you want the results grouped with those additional columns, then it's simply a matter of adding them into the above select column and group by lists, e.g.:

```
SELECT current_year_date,
       previous_year__date,
       product_category,
       customer_category,
       sales_channel,
       <SUM columns>
FROM   pos.snapshot_summary_log
GROUP BY current_year_date,
         previous_year__date,
         product_category,
         customer_category,
         sales_channel;
```

I've not done anything with the columns; you may want to throw an outer query around this that adds the snap and hist columns together, or maybe COALESCEs them, but I'll leave that up to you to decide.